# Join us for #MageStackDay on Feburary 13th & 14th

Tags: discussion, magestackday, community, event

Back by popular demand:

**The second edtion of MageStackDay will happen on February 13th & 14th!**

MageStackDay is an **online hackathon** dedicated to answering, closing and cleaning up questions on magento.stackexchange.com. The goal will be to get the answered questions rate up by at least a few percent and get more users active on this platform.

Please help us **spreading the word** about #MageStackDay on twitter, IRC, facebook groups, developer events and wherever you meet people willing to join us for this event!

More information:
http://www.magestackday.com

Comment: Anna,is it not possible to reschedule at  23th and 24th January?

Comment: No, sorry. This date is set for the next MageStackDay. Next week would be also too short for preparation.

Comment: Thanks Anna.Lets gear up magento stackexchnage

Comment: hi Anna,Can you please tell me from time of 13feb stack will start .Please let me know time at GMT